# unable to start wireshark

Tags: libraries, wireshark

I have a system that runs ARCO linux (Arch based). I've used it to run wireshark just fine previously. I then wanted to use an older version of wireshark, and went and got the sources for wireshark-2.6.10 but they did not compile completely due to some compiler error (extern "C" in layout_preferences_frame.cpp:12)and I decided to give up on it. I'd uninstalled my current version of wireshark with pacman and then re-installed it but for some reason, now it won't launch anymore and instead I get:

```
wireshark
wireshark: error while loading shared libraries: libwscodecs.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I could not find what `libwscodecs.so.2` exactly is or how I can get it back, none of my other systems seems to have it either (but wireshark works fine there). What happened< I'm wondering and hgow can I get my wireshark up & running again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Debian machine (sorry not Arch) I do have the the shared library at the following location:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwscodecs.so.2`

What I would check is to see if there are dependencies that got broken when you tried to install manually.  It is also possible that an older version of the shared library was compiled as part of your efforts and is in place of the old one.

One thing that you could so is uninstall wireshark again, then run:

`pacman -Rs $(pacman -Qtdq)`

to try and see if their are orphaned packages that could be removed.  This could be a "back door" to get everything installed cleanly again.

Another thing to do is to see if any of the dependencies show on the webpage (https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/wireshark-qt/) for the wireshark package are broken.  You can also search the website to see if that shared object is included in any of the wireshark packages.  I did not find it in a short look.  Is it possible that a configure (for compiling) or config (like /etc/) file were changed to look for the libwscodecs.so.2?

Another follow up.  What does pacman show as the dependencies for the other machines that are working fine.  Is there a difference compared to the machine that is providing the error?

Comment: Boom, that did it, it conmplained about a conflicting `/usr/bin/wireshark` but after rebaming that it installed and can be started fine! Great, Thanks!